# What are the software updated when I updated through the default software updater gui?

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager

Automatically the ubuntu asks for its users to update the latest updates, but all the time I am unaware what gets updated. 
 ***How am I supposed to know what are the updates installed?
 how can I manage the updates and install knowing my necessity?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what apt did in the log file:

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
```

The software updater tells you what it is about to update when it asks for your permission to do so. You can check there what you want to update and what not.

Answer (score 1):

The software updater dialog has a "Details of updates" section.  If you click on this, you can see a list of the software that will be updated as part of this.  You can also check/uncheck software.

You can also see this list via the commandline using

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --dry-run
```

[image]

Comment: Ofcourse it shows the lists of softwares that are being installed but as a beginner I don't even know what those software titles are supposed to do in my system. Basically I use few softwares and why am I getting hundreds of mb to update?